# Web Application Server Issues

Tags: c#, iis-6

I have a web application saved on a server. I want to be able to create an XML file for each user that logs onto the web app (using the users Windows log in when on the domain. The users log in needs to be the file name of the XML file.

I want to then save the file to a shared drive.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up a service which is called on log event. On your service, you have to write your xml file and save it as the user name. The user name can be catched with HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.

Is it what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to break up the process you are describing into logical and simple to achieve tasks.

1. Authenticate a user using Windows Authentication and Impersonation.
2. Access the user's domain username.
3. Create an XML file on a shared drive.
4. Open and edit an XML file on a shared drive.

Each of these tasks are relatively easy and have many resources on the web for how to achieve them using your language of choice.

If you are having trouble doing one of the particular parts of the process you describe above, be specific with what you are having a problem achieving, and we can help.

Comment: I have got to the stage where I can save the file to an XML document on the server using the user ID as stated in the below answer. I did this by Turning the Anonymous off and assigning an ASP User account to the Application Pool which has access to the drive I want to store it on(on another server). That works fine when running on the server but when I connect to the server via the browser on my PC I am required to put in a username and password (which it wont accept anything). Hope you can help with this

Comment: Create new question for it and add more information. Note: debuggin the exception will most likley show you the problem - check Environment.UserName right before writing to file.